# Custom function in R using pmap_int

Tags: r, purrr

In R, I have created a function to repeat a series of calculations given different input parameters.
I am trying to use pmap_int() to pass the parameters and get the result from my function. Example:

```
unique_id = seq(1:5)
pos = seq(1.1,1.5, by =  0.1)
cpc = seq(11:15)
clicks = seq(30,50, by =5)
times = seq(2,10, by =2)
df<-data.frame(unique_id,pos,cpc,clicks, times)

myfunction<-function(n_clicks, position, weighted_cpc){
 t<- df %>% 
 filter(clicks/times>n_clicks & pos<position & cpc>weighted_cpc) %>%
 summarise(n_kwd = length(unique_id)) 
 return(t)  
 }

test <- tibble(
 n_clicks = rep(c(0,10), each = 6),
 position = rep(seq(1.1,1.3,by= 0.1),4),
 weighted_cpc = rep(seq(0.10,0.20, by= 0.1),6))


test %>% 
  pmap_int(n_clicks,position,weighted_cpc, myfunction)
```

This returns an error: "Error: Result 1 is not a length 1 atomic vector". 
However, if I pass each element of the tibble individually to the myfunction, it gives the desired result. EG:

```
myfunction(test$n_clicks[1],test$position[1],test$weighted_cpc[1])
```

Do you have any idea of what is happening? I think it may be the way the function is returning the results but I can find a way to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Using your code, I get a different error, `object 'n_clicks' not found'`, which is obvious.  Check `?pmap_int`.  You must pass just two arguments, `.f` and `.l`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing arguments to `pmap_int` correctly. Check the documentation. It expects a list as the first parameter (or tibble) and a function as the second. It does not expect column names. The call should look more like

```
test %>% 
  pmap_int(myfunction)
```

If you are trying to use column names, then you would need to do that inside some sort of mutate

```
test %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(z=myfunction(n_clicks, position, weighted_cpc))
```

Here I used `rowwise()` because your function is not vectorized. This will also return a tibble with the new column added as opposed to the former version which returns just the values.

Also if you use the `_int` version your custom function should return an integer. You seems to be returning a tibble. Your function should look like

```
myfunction <- function(n_clicks, position, weighted_cpc){
  df %>% 
    filter(clicks/times>n_clicks & pos<position & cpc>weighted_cpc) %>%
    summarise(n_kwd = length(unique_id)) %>%
    pull(n_kwd)
}
```

Comment: It is my understanding that "pull" works for returning one argument, what would I use instead if I had multiple elements to be returned? For example, if summarise created not only n_kwd but also other metrics. Thanks!

Comment: Answer to my question:  
`myfunction<-function(n_clicks, position, weighted_cpc){
          for (i in c(1:length(n_clicks))){
           t<- df %>% 
              filter(clicks/occurance_in_tbl>n_clicks & pos<position & w_cpc>weighted_cpc) %>%
              summarise(n_kwd = length(unique_id),
                        costs = sum(cost),
                        clicks = sum(clicks),
                        nits_conversions = sum(nits_conversions)
                        ) %>% 
             mutate(n_clicks, position, weighted_cpc)
             }
            return(t) 
          }`

Answer (score 0):

I dont' know why this doesn't work but it can be fixed with this code:

```
test %>% 
  pmap(myfunction) %>% 
  unlist()
n_kwd n_kwd n_kwd n_kwd n_kwd n_kwd n_kwd n_kwd n_kwd n_kwd n_kwd n_kwd 
    0     1     2     0     1     2     0     1     1     0     1     1
```